# Logical IF function to choose one of 3 options

Tags: excel-formula

I have a dropdown menu with "-,I,Z" and I want 3 seperate choices for this options, I have tried the below formula, but doesnt seam to work

=IF(G17="I","Text 1",IF(AND(G17="Z",G17="-"),"Text 2","Text 3"))

Please help, I couldn't fins a similar scenario in here.

Comment: You want OR not AND

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because of the AND function says G17 has to be BOTH Z and - simultaneously, which is impossible. If you change it to an OR function it should work

I would recommend the IFS function to make it more readable:

```
=IFS(G17="I","Text 1",OR(G17="Z",G17="-"),"Text 2", TRUE(), "Text 3"))
```